# H2o AutoML in R: XGBoost is not available; skipping it

Tags: r, linux, h2o, automl, h2o.ai

I'm trying to run H2o's automl and I want to see the results of XGboost in automl. When I'm trying to run this code:

```
aml1 <- h2o.automl(y = y, x = x, training_frame = train, keep_cross_validation_models = F, seed = 123)
```

I'm getting this message:

> |                            |   0%
> 16:25:37.796: AutoML: XGBoost is not available; skipping it.
> Job $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_8c51b0759fd2e77fd8940b41f83340c2 was cancelled.

I'm using H2o 3.32.1.1 version on a Centos 7 linux server. I'm using R 3.6.0 version. I installed H2o using:

`install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_R")))` 
as given in:
https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/downloading.html

Please help. I don't know why xgboost is not running in automl. And, how it could be fixed. I couldn't find any solution online yet to solve this issue.

**EDIT**

Issue got resolved by installing `xgboost` package in R. Thanks guys for your comments and directing me towards installing `xgboost` in R.

Comment: From the docs: "XGBoost is used only if it is available globally and if it hasn’t been explicitly disabled. You can check if XGBoost is available by using the h2o.xgboost.available() in R"; so it looks like you need to install xgboost globally (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-linux-distributions)

Comment: @jared_mamrot That's not correct, you don't need to install the xgboost R package to use XGBoost in H2O.  They are totally separate things.  H2O comes bundled with XGBoost unless you by-hand, specifically build a version w/o XGB support.

The only place XGBoost doesn't work via H2O is in Windows, so this should work on CentOS.  

Can you clarify how you resolved the issue?  Installing the xgboost R package would not fix anything with H2O, so I am not sure what that means.

Comment: I understand that H2O comes bundled with xgboost, and that installing xgboost through R should not be necessary, but my advice is based on my own experience with a similar package (not H2O) where xgboost couldn't locate 'something' and installing xgboost globally fixed my issue. It also appears to have worked in this case (from the question edit above): "Issue got resolved by installing xgboost package in R. Thanks guys for your comments and directing me towards installing xgboost in R." but I cannot say _why_ this workaround would solve the problem sorry

Comment: @jared_mamrot I think installing xgboost in R brought in some dependencies that were missing. That is some great out-of-the-box thinking, I wouldn't thought of that - as would probably most of the other users. We need to get better at reporting why XGBoost is not available. I would like to reproduce your issue - can you share details of your Centos 7 installation? What version exactly, what kind of install - eg. "minimal install" / "compute node"/...?

Comment: @ErinLeDell I have posted in my edit that installing xgboost package in R solved the issue. Erin, it did fix the issue. After installing xgboost in R; h2o's automl started building XGBoost models as well (earlier it was giving a warning that XGBoost not available; so skipping it). jared_mamrot I think you're right installing xgboost fixed something globally because of which H2o's automl started building XGBoost models. Michal Kurka sure I'll share my Centos 7 installation details

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thanks for helping - i am surprised that this would affect it, but I am willing to believe it did, even though I don't quite yet understand how.  Usually I just assume there's some context missing when something doesn't make sense and I was hoping to get more info... sorry for making assumptions.